# Type Conversion for data transmission

Tags: floating-point, type-conversion, arrays

i have a problem converting data between different types. I know there are a lot of Questions and How-to's regarding this topic, but i wasn't able to succeed with any of those.

I have a transmission line using byte arrays. I have float values, put them into a byte array, send them and then convert them back to floats. Easy enough I thougt.

I've tried unions, casts and different things and then to get to the lowest level possible just memcpy and bitshifts, but still just ****

One could narrow it down to the folling example. As I understand it, this procedure should transform the float value into a byte array and back.

```
float32_t value;
byte dataPacket[20] = {0};

value = 500.0; /
memcpy(&dataPacket[0], &value, 4); 
value = (dataPacket[0]<<24)| (dataPacket[1]<<16) | (dataPacket[2]<<8) | dataPacket[3]);
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm wrong?

I know there are probably easier ways to do that, but I can't see why this wouldn't work :-(

Thanks for the help!

EDIT:

The bitshifts are ment to verify the content of the byte buffer since I think that there is a problem. In my application the byte array is sent to an android device. There the array is put into a byte buffer. Then I can easyly output float values. The values I get there are the same values the bitshift operations give me in the example above. So I assume the data is not correctly stored in the byte array.

I hope this is understandable. Sometime I write a little confusing when using english. Please ask if something is unclear.

Comment: The line `value = (dataPacket[0]<<24)...` assumes big endian and casts an `int` to `float32_t` using arithmetic conversion. Why don't you simply `memcpy` from `dataPacket` back to `value`?

Comment: Actually the bitshift stuff was just to test if the data in the packet is correct. and since even that did not work, i assumed something was wrong. The data is transfered to an android device where I use an byte buffer object to extract the float values. The values i get there are equal to the values I get when using the bitshift stuff. Therefore I assume, that somewhere, somewhat went wrong...